# How to execute a graphics C++ program on macOS Sierra

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, glfw

I'm working on a project for my graphics class, which the professor provided the base code. He coded it up with our lab computers (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) in mind. I wanted to work on this project from my own computer at home, but I cant seem to figure out how to run it.

I do know the Makefile he gave us is specific to the lab computers, once again, but I'm not skilled enough to figure out how to alter it for a macOS.

**Makefile**

```
CPP = g++ -std=c++11
INC = -I../glslutil -I../mvcutil -I.
C_FLAGS = -fPIC -g -c -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES $(INC)

LINK = g++ -fPIC -g
LOCAL_UTIL_LIBRARIES = ../lib/libglsl.so
GL_LIB_LOC = -L/usr/lib/nvidia-375
GL_LIBRARIES = $(GL_LIB_LOC) -lglfw -lGLU -lGL

OBJS = project1.o ModelView.o Controller.o GLFWController.o

project1: $(OBJS) $(LOCAL_UTIL_LIBRARIES)
    $(LINK) -o project1 $(OBJS) $(LOCAL_UTIL_LIBRARIES) $(GL_LIBRARIES)

../lib/libglsl.so: ../glslutil/ShaderIF.h ../glslutil/ShaderIF.c++
    (cd ../glslutil; make)

project1.o: project1.c++
    $(CPP) $(C_FLAGS) project1.c++
ModelView.o: ModelView.h ModelView.c++
    $(CPP) $(C_FLAGS) ModelView.c++
Controller.o: ../mvcutil/Controller.h ../mvcutil/Controller.c++
    $(CPP) $(C_FLAGS) ../mvcutil/Controller.c++
GLFWController.o: ../mvcutil/GLFWController.h 
    ../mvcutil/GLFWController.c++
$(CPP) $(C_FLAGS) ../mvcutil/GLFWController.c++
```

Although, I'm not even sure that's the problem. I just want to see the graphics on my laptop! :) I appreciate any help!

Overall, I would like to see something similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59A8a.jpg) on my mac.

My [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ymvp.png) when compiling on my mac.

Comment: We don't have your source code, so we can't build this to see what's wrong. What errors are you getting? Please include the exact error message in your post.

Answer (score 2):

I, personally, wouldn't go that way, unless you really have to.

I'd go a different path:

- download VirtualBox from here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
- download Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
- ask your teacher what exact packages does he use for the class
- install Ubuntu 16.04 inside VirtualBox
- install all packages required by your teacher
- use VirtualBox installation for this particular class

This way, you will save lots of time and effort.

Comment: That's a MUCH better idea! Good thinking.

Comment: .oOo. Thanks! .oOo.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is going to be rather hard to do, and this is only a partial answer, so maybe some other kind folk will know how to do the other half, or 80% - not even sure how much I am missing.

The Makefile looks like it is using `glslang` and `glfw` and some Nvidia library. To get some of those packages on a Mac, you would need to:

- install **Xcode** - start AppStore, find and download **Xcode** for free
- install **Command Line Tools** with `xcode-select --install` in Terminal
- install **homebrew** - goto [Homebrew website](http://brew.sh)

Then you could search for your packages with

```
brew search glfw
brew search glslang
```

Then you can find out what the packages are with:

```
brew info glfw
```

**Sample Output**

```
glfw: stable 3.2.1 (bottled), HEAD
Multi-platform library for OpenGL applications
http://www.glfw.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/glfw.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✘
==> Options
--with-examples
    Build examples
--with-test
    Build test programs
--without-shared-library
    Build static library only (defaults to building dylib only)
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

Then install it with:

```
brew install glfw
```

You will still probably have a load of problems and I cannot find the Nvidia stuff... maybe someone else can add more help.